# 1サーバーにdockerで複数webサーバー立ち上げてLBは、負荷分散になる?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

VPSにdocker入れて、webサーバーコンテナを複数立ち上げます。
ホストにはnginx入れてアクセス時に各コンテナへロードバランシングするとします。

これは負荷分散の効果があるのでしょうか？

各サーバーコンテナへは負荷が分散されますが、
ホストへの負荷は変わらないのではないかと考えているのですが...

Comment: 負荷分散効果があると思うに至った理由などがあれば、それを記述すると回答がつきやすくなるかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。質問した理由ですが、現場でそのような構築になっているサーバーがありました。既に退社させているので聞くに聞けずという状態でした。負荷分散なのか他の意図なのか気になり、質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 6):

1台のサーバ内でWebサーバ用コンテナを複数稼働しても負荷分散にはならず、むしろコンテナを稼働するオーバーヘッドが加算されて負加増になるかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

負荷分散ではなく可用性なのでは？
1プロセス死んでも、サービス続けられますよね？